# How to upload multiple csv files to a SQL server Database using R

Tags: r, sql-server, dbi, dbplyr

I have a number folders that store >50 different csv files in each folder, each with different names, different number of variables, and lengths. I have to upload them to a SQL server (SSMS) and instead of having to upload them one by one I would like to ask how to batch upload them all at once, *especially* their unique names (i.e. Demographics, Biologic, Sites, Labs, OthLabs, Subjects, etc.) and they are not big (under 5mb per folder). I've tried creating a list `csv <- dir(pattern = "csv")` but haven't figured out how to use it with `DBI::dbWriteTable(conn = con, name = , value = , overwrite = FALSE)` . I would be very grateful if someone has dealt with this in the past could help me.

**Update**

the tables in question are all different, having different dimensions and lengths (i.e.(130,12), (151,33), (1,6), (603, 16), etc.), what i'm trying to do is to upload them with their names. I've tried the code bellow

```
alldat <- lapply(csv, read.csv) 
for (i in alldat) {
dbWriteTable(conn = con,
 name = "i",
 value =  i,
 overwrite = FALSE)
  }
```

yes it works, but will create only 1 table called "i", any recommendation on what should  the arguments for `name =`  and `value =`  be so that the loop will continue copying the tables from R to SQL server with the table names?

other functions that I've tried unsuccessfully are `list2env`, `assign` `do.call(rbind, i)`

Comment: `dbplyr` does not export `dbWriteTable`, that's from `DBI` (and likely from the specific driver you're using, e.g., `odbc`). If they are not big, and `read.csv` works, then `alldat <- lapply(csv, read.csv)` followed by `for (x in alldat) dbWriteTable(con, "sometable", x)` might be one way, or perhaps `dbWriteTable(con, "sometable", do.call(rbind, x))` if they are homogeneous.

Comment: My apologies, you are correct, I confused from what package the function came from for a moment! made the edit and this helps a lot! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after finally trying my hand on writing functions and a loop this is what I came up with! thanks to @Simon.S.A. and @r2evans for their input

```
library(dbi)

# Connect to the SQL Server database
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      driver = "SQL Server",
                      server = "server_name",
                      database = "database_name",
                      uid = "username",
                      pwd = "password")

# Set the path to the folder containing the CSV files
folder <- "C:/path/to/folder"

#Get a list of the CSV files in the folder
csv_files <- list.files(folder, pattern = "\\.csv$")`

#Loop through the CSV files
for (csv_file in csv_files) {
  # Read the CSV file into a data frame
  df <- read.csv(file.path(folder, csv_file))
  
  # Get the name of the table to import the data into
  table_name <- gsub("\\.csv$", "", csv_file)
  
  # Import the data into the SQL Server database
  dbWriteTable(con, table_name, df)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @r2evans I do this using DBI, rather than dbplyr (I often use the two packages together).

Below is a cut down version of the custom function I use. You can find the full version [here](https://github.com/simon-anasta/dbplyr_helpers/blob/master/dbplyr_helper_functions.R).

```r
copy_r_to_sql <- function(db_connection, db, schema, sql_table_name, r_table_name) {

  suppressMessages( # mutes translation message
    DBI::dbWriteTable(
      db_connection,
      DBI::Id(
        catalog = db,
        schema = schema,
        table = sql_table_name
      ),
      r_table_name
    )
  )
}
```

For uploading multiple tables, either loop through them or `apply`.

Comment: I get an error in the error in evaluating the argument 'name' in selecting a method for function 'dbWriteTable' , it should be a list correct?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your question. What should be a list?

Comment: Sorry about that, I've been trying to pass your function through apply, and still haven't found a way to be able to get their names to appear in SQL Server and have been thinking on how to do it but  have been unsuccessful using assign

Comment: Most of my uses of `apply` involve functions where only one variable changes. It seems likely this would require a minimum of two variables changing: `sql_table_name` and `r_table_name` (or `csv_file_name`). Perhaps if you modify the function to take a list of csv file names, and to write the csv file into an sql table with the same name as the file. Then `sql_table_name` and `csv_file_name` would be the same thing.

Comment: Okay thanks! i'll give it a try and let you know!